# Добавить в массив значение ключа объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть некий объект:

```
"MOSCOW": {
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Хочу преобразовать объект в массив. Для этого использую `.map()`:

```
let array = $.map(data, function(value, i) {
    return value;
});
```

Но хочу добавить в начало массива новый элемент, значение которого равнялось бы значению ключа массива:

```
{
    "name": "MOSCOW",
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: у тебя результат все еще _объект_.

Comment: @Grundy теперь массив.

Comment: а вот и нет. `{
    "name": "MOSCOW",
    "foo": "bar"
}` - это объект

Comment: @Grundy это называется Array-Like Object, по-моему. Там есть свойство length.

Comment: В твоем примере свойства length нет, в любом случае только наличие length не делает из объекта массив

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin у Array-Like Object ещё и индексы должны быть числами.

Comment: а вообще этого чтоли хочется ? `return $.extend(value, {name: i});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я так понял нужно просто добавить в значение поле name, не забываем делать deep clone.

```js
const data = {
  "MOSCOW": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "SPB": {
    "food": "arb"
  }

};
const arr = $.map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), (value, i) => $.extend(value, {
  name: i
}));
console.log(arr, data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```